# SQL update statement error after i add a column to a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I have a table called [user], and I add one more column to the table using simple alter table statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [user]
ADD Company nvarchar(50) null
```

When I try to do simple update like the following

```
 UPDATE dbo.[User] 
   SET  username = 'al'
             WHERE UserId = 17
```

I am getting an error

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure User_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE, Line
>   6 [Batch Start Line 26]
>
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

If I drop the column every thing works fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems, the error is in the `INSERT INTO dbo.[User]` block some where else. You need to manullay mention the column names in the `INSERT INTO dbo.[User]` to fix the issue

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Any triggers involved?

Comment: Is there any trigger on user table? You need to check this procedure first User_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE . What is there in Line 6? Or else you can edit your question and paste the code of the procedure if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error from the update statement. This error comes from an insert statement, where the columns list is missing. This is one of the main reasons (but not the only one) of why you should always specify the columns list in an insert statement.

You should look elsewhere in the `User_INSERT_UPDATE_DELETE` procedure (or trigger) to find and fix this problem. In fact, you should probably go over all the procedures in the database that contains `insert` statements and make sure all the insert statements contains the columns list, to avoid having to deal with such an error again.

The proper way to write an `insert` statement in T-SQL is this:

```
INSERT INTO <TableName> (Column_1 [, Column_2, ... Column_n])
VALUES (Value_1 [, Value_2, ... Value_n])
```

Or this:

```
INSERT INTO <TableName> (Column_1 [, Column_2, ... Column_n])
SELECT Value_1 [, Value_2, ... Value_n]
FROM <OtherTableOrView>
```

Comment: And let's add to this - when you alter a table you need to find and review the dependencies of that table to determine if any other code bits should be updated for that schema change.